# Numpy: Computing sum(array[i, a[i]:b[i]]) for all rows i

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum, slice

I have a numpy array `arr` and a list of slice start points `start` and a list of slice endpoints `end`. For each row `i`, I want to determine the sum of the elements from `start[i]` to `end[i]`. That is, I want to determine

```
[np.sum(arr[i, start[i]:end[i]]) for i in range(arr.shape[0])]
```

Is there a smarter/faster way to do this using numpy only?

Comment: I think you're going to want to flatten `arr` and use [`numpy.add.reduceat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) to compute sums.

Comment: That has the unfortunate effect of computing a bunch of sums you don't need with the other parts of `arr`, though. I don't know of a good way to avoid that without writing an explicit loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach using [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
# Create range array corresponding to the length of the no. of cols
r = np.arange(arr.shape[1])

# Mask of ranges corresponding to the start and end indices using broadcasting
mask = (start[:,None] <= r) & (end[:,None] > r)

# Finally, we use the mask to select and sum rows using einsum
out = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',arr,mask)
```

Comment: I like this answer!